# Grouping points generated by a Kinect in C++

Tags: c++, image-processing, kinect, cluster-analysis

Is there any algorithm or preferably a code snippet to organize and group nearly placed points (organized within a radius or specific number of neighbors) generated from a point cloud image  by a Kinect and convert that into one point. I want to increase the size and thereby reduce the number of points.

Comment: **What have you tried**? There are some pretty straightforward approaches, and there are smart algorithms such as DBSCAN (look it up on Wikipedia) for such problems, too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a wide topic called "cluster analysis". Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) for more info. You should do some experiments with several clustering methods.

Answer (score 0):

One simple method is the following:

1. fix an "epsilon" value that you want to use for clustering
2. for each point compute a "cluster key" from the coordinates
3. add all points to a map indexed by the cluster key
4. collect all groups by checking a cluster and nearby clusters only

in code:

```
std::map<CellIndex, std::vector<P3d> > pmap;

for (int  i=0,n=pts.size(); i<n; i++)
{
    int ix = int(pts[i].x / eps);
    int iy = int(pts[i].y / eps);
    int iz = int(pts[i].z / eps);
    pmap[CellIndex(ix, iy, iz)].push_back(pts[i]);
}

for (std::map<CellIndex, std::vector<P3d> >::iterator i=pmap.begin(),e=pmap.end();
     i != e;
     ++i)
{
    // get cluster center
    int cx = i->first.ix;
    int cy = i->first.iy;
    int cz = i->first.iz;

    // collect points from all 9 cluster with x index between cx-1 and cx+1
    // between cy-1 and cy+1 and between cz-1 and cz+1 (inclusive).
    // Not all clusters are guaranteed to be present in the map.
    // You will be considering only points that are at most 1.5*sqrt(3)*eps from
    // the center of the (cx, cy, cz) cell.
}
```

Depending on the computation you need to do sometimes is possible to perform just one pass
by keeping intermediate results in the cells itself instead of storing the points in them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using *mean Shift*?